# When was magnetic field, first, mathematically defined?

Tags: magnetic-fields, definition, units

The reason I'm asking this is, that we see that there is a constant $\mu$, in biot-Savart's law.  If they were the first one to define it why did they use a constant? They could have simply left the expression as it is, without the constant.

So, was there anyone else who had defined magnetic field/flux before them?

Comment: Perhaps this will help as a stsrting off point? - [Magnetism](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/EarthSci/people/lidunka/GEOL2014/Geophysics9%20-Magnetism/Useful%20papers/Magnetism.htm)

Comment: Maybe this question belongs to hsm SE

Comment: Units of the two sides of BS law, without such constant, could not match. So you need it. Very similar things you can find in fluid dynamics, the law is the same, while constat is of course different.

Answer (score 0):

They probably measured the force between conductors. It was interpreted as a magnetic force because compass needles are also deflected by a current.

$$\frac{F} {\Delta L} = \frac{\mu I_1I_2}{2\pi r} $$
As that forces, for the currents from the available batteries, were very tiny, the units for $I$ would be too small without a small constant.